# How to add text to an initial text in a TinyMCE textarea?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

i have an initial template when i init tinymce, i have several paragraphs and i need to add some text on one of them.

On my text area template i have something like this:

```
<p>bla bla bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla bla bla <span id="newText"></span></p>
<p>bla bla bla bla bla</p>
```

using jquery im trying something like this:

```
$("span#newText").append("new text");
```

but it doesnt work. If i execute this command on the console browser, i can see the new text on the textarea.

is this possible?

Comment: Are you trying to change the content in the editor after its taken over control of the textarea?

Comment: no. i would like to add content before

Answer (score 0):

Where are you writting the jQuery script? You have to put it after the textarea... or you can use something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("span#newText").append("new text");
});
```

Comment: yes, i have the script after the textarea into $(document).ready(function() {});

Answer (score 0):

im using twig (symfony) and i put this script at the bottom of the twig file.

I'm really using a "change" event of a select tag. I have more scripts like datepicker and modernizr that works.

this twig is a form with 2 input, one select, the textarea with the template and a submit button.

all i want to do is when i change the option on the select, add the value to the middle of the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already initialized TinyMCE on a textarea updating the underlying textarea's content won't update the editor.  When you first call `init` any HTML in the textarea would be loaded into TinyMCE but if you are updating the textarea based on something like `document.ready()` its possible that the editor is already in its initialization process and done looking at the textarea.

The best way to load the content into the editor would be to use TinyMCE's `init` API:

```
tinymce.init({
   selector: "#myTextarea",
   ...
   setup: function (editor) {
       editor.on('init', function () {
           editor.setContent('This is the content to load into the editor');
       }
   }
});
```

The `init` call won't fire until TinyMCE itself is fulling initialized (this is often after `document.ready()` would be true) so at that point you can pass in whatever data you want.  As the TinyMCE init is Javascript you can certainly pass in a variable that contains the relevant HTML as opposed to the hard coded string in my example.

***UPDATE:***  Per your comment see this updated JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4m69mjjx/4/

All you need to do is use the appropriate TinyMCE API to insert HTML based on the value of the select list:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    tinymce.get('textbox').insertContent(this.value);  
});
```

Comment: i put an example on http://jsfiddle.net/4m69mjjx/2/  .when i select an option, i would like add the value to the textarea

Comment: @user1939481 see the update to my answer for more details on how to do what you want.

Comment: thank you for your response and time but i think i cant explain good. I need to insert the selected value on the span with id "newText" but reading your previous response, I'm not sure if it's possible to do it

Comment: The code in my updated JS fiddle shows you how to insert content at the cursor when you select an item from the list.  You can modify it any way you need to insert whatever HTML you need.  What part do you not understand?  What have you tried based on the updated fiddle?